# How to display login error message on the same page in a php based system?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a php based login system where the user is required to put in a username and password for logging in. My question is 'how can I display the 'invalid username or password' error message on the same page'? I have tried many things including trying to use a query string (/?error=1); it did solve my problem by displaying the error message on the same page but all the CSS was just gone from the page and I couldn't find a way to fix it (not for the lack of trying, though). So I decided to try a simpler method which, obviously, did not work. 
So, how can I fix it?
Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","combination");
if(isset($_POST['login_btn'])){

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $password=md5($password);
    $sqlquery="SELECT * FROM registration WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sqlquery);


    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){

        $_SESSION['message']="You are now logged in.";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

        header("location:loginhome.php");
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['message']="Incorrect Username or Password."; 
        header("location:login.php");
        echo '<h3>Invalid username or password</h3>';
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: For starters, you can't use a header and echo together.

Comment: you're also mixing different mysql apis and that code is totally unsafe to use in a live environment

Comment: plus the html form's unknown. Best you check for errors and read the official manuals

Comment: this is not correct , echo your session  $_SESSION['message'] in your html form. if you can set $_SESSION['error_type'] = 0 success $_SESSION['error_type']  = 1 for error and  var then echo it

Comment: don't store passwords in plain text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple example to help you. You need to use `$_SESSION` variables.

**login.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="check.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" class="input" name="username" placeholder="username">
            <input  type="password" class="input" name="pass" placeholder="pass">
            <input class="button" type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="login">  
                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION["error"])){
                        $error = $_SESSION["error"];
                        echo "<span>$error</span>";
                    }
                ?>  
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    unset($_SESSION["error"]);
?>
```

**check.php:**

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST["username"];
$error = "username/password incorrect";

if($username == "admin"){
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    header("location: homepage.php"); //send user to homepage, for example.
}else{
    $_SESSION["error"] = $error;
    header("location: login.php"); //send user back to the login page.
}

?>
```

Comment: can i use session for error for all of my fields. or using too much session may consume unnecessary resources?

Comment: You can use session variables. Just make sure to remove them after the form has passed.

Comment: yeah.. i unset all after closing html tag